# Converting jQuery Request to Axios

Tags: javascript, jquery, axios

I have an app that was written in jQuery. I'm trying to modernize it. As part of that, I'm trying to convert a jQuery request to Axios. My jQuery request looks like this:

```
var myUrl = '[someUrl]';
var myData = {
  firstName: 'Joe',
  lastName: 'Smith'
};

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST', url: myUrl, cache: 'false',
  contentType:'application/json',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'key': '12345'
  },
  data: JSON.stringify(myData),
  success: onSearchSuccess,
  error: onSearchFailure,
  complete: onSearchComplete
});
```

Now, with my modern code, I have the following:

```
var myUrl = '[someUrl]';
var myData = {
  firstName: 'Joe',
  lastName: 'Smith'
};
axios.post(myUrl, myData)
  .then(function (response) {
    alert('yeah!');
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    alert('oops');
    console.log(error);
  })
;
```

I'm not sure how to pass in the headers or if I need to stringify `myData`. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the [manual](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)? :)

Here's what you need:

> axios.post(url[, data[, config]])

The way you translate that into code is:

```
var myUrl = '[someUrl]';
var myData = {
  firstName: 'Joe',
  lastName: 'Smith'
};
axios.post(myUrl, myData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'key': '12345'
    }
    // other configuration there
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    alert('yeah!');
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    alert('oops');
    console.log(error);
  })
;
```

The returned object implements the [A+ Promise API](https://promisesaplus.com/). Based on your configuration you may need to polyfill that, but there are a lot of packages available on in the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=promise).

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) is implementation of A+ Promise. I used it for old browser support. You might want to use it too.